# How to reduce a given series expression to an algebraic expression?

Tags: big-o

I need to reduce the given series expression to an algebraic expression, without summation.

Then I have to express the performance of the algebraic expression in Big O Notation.

I am mainly confused about the first part. I am not too sure how to interpret the series expression to an algebraic expression. An explanation would be great! Thanks.

Algorithm of:

```
for ( j = 0; j < n; j++ )

{

 for ( k = j; k < n; k++ )

 {



 }

}
will result in a number of iterations of given by the expression:

 = n + (n-1) + (n-2) + (n-3) + ........ + (n - n)
```

Answer (score 0):

For `j=0` there are `n` values of `k`.
For `j=1` there are `n-1` values of `k`.
For `j=2` there are `n-2` values of `k`.
...
For `j=n-2` there are `n-(n-2)` values of `k`.
For `j=n-1` there are `n-(n-1)` values of `k`.

Therefore, the inner loop will have:

```
n + (n-1) + ... + (n-(n-2)) + (n-(n-1))
```

iterations.

Although there are many techniques mathematicians use, there is no general recipe for transforming an expression to a *closed form*, i.e., to an algebraic expression with a fixed number of operations `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` (meaning that this number does not depend on the parameter `n`).

So, you basically have to know some few well-known transformations in advance, and combine them the best you can.

In the example above what we can do is rewriting the expression as:

```
sum_{j=0}{n-1} (n - j)
```

and then operate on it like this:

```
sum_{j=0}^{n-1} (n - j) = Σ(n-j)                     ; 0 ≤ j ≤ n-1
                        = Σn - Σj                    ; regroup
                        = n*n - (n-1)n/2             ; see below
                        = n(n+1)/2                   ; n is common factor
```

Here the well-known formula is the one I've used for replacing `Σj` which you will find explained in many places. The first substitution `Σn = n*n` is trivial because we are adding `n` to itself `n` times.